# Icefaces ace:autoCompleteEntry not working

Tags: icefaces, icefaces-3

I'm trying to use ace:autoCompleteEntry but it doesn't seem to work. I use it as simple as possible by just having a f:selectItems child. If I change the component to h:selectOneMenu then everything works fine so there is nothing wrong with f:selectItems. My question is if anyone has worked with the component and can confirm that is working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be of any help but I had the same issue and I just found out that `ace:autoCompleteEntry` doesn't work if it's inside an `ace:tabSet`. Was that your case?

It works well with `ice:panelTabSet` instead.

Answer (score 0):

based on my experiment,

just add `<ace:ajax execute="@this" />` under `f:selectItems` (inside `ace:autoCompleteEntry`)

it will activate its dropdown